# jQuery plugin architecture issue for calling plugin's method without initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

I have made a jQuery plugin to perform form validation before submitting the form to the server.

**for example**

**case 1.** I can call the following function directly.

```
 $('#btnSubmit').formValidator();
```

**case 2.** but if I want to call the function like this to perform addtional logic after validation and before submitting the form to server-

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).formValidator("execute")) {
                    //addtional logic
                }
            })
```

but In **case 2** am **not able to call the function**.

the full code is here - https://jsfiddle.net/xLs298yc/
would appreciate a little help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
                if ($(this).formValidator("execute")) {
                    //addtional logic
                }
            })
```

Did you try this ?

```
if ($("#"+this.id).formValidator("execute"))
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't worked and while calling so, it throws unknown plugin data found